# How to pass the path for link_to tag from controller to view.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, path, controller

Now I'm trying to make path markup.

Assume it's up to 4th depth level directory then I made something like this for view?
How can I pass the path to view from controller with variable label???

```
          <% if !@FirstDirPath.nil? %>
          <%= @FirstDirPath %> <span class="divider">/</span>
          <% end %>

          <% if !@SecondDirPath.nil? %>
          <%= @SecondDirPath %> <span class="divider">/</span>
          <% end %>

          <% if !@ThirdDirPath.nil? %>
          <%= @ThirdDirPath %> <span class="divider">/</span>
          <% end %>

          <% if !@FourthDirPath.nil? %>
          <%= @FourthDirPath %> <span class="divider">/</span>
          <% end %>
```

Comment: this is not the way rails should work. i suggest you reed this first: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: How do you manage if the link destination is variable like in this case??? What's the normal and efficient way? please tell me if you knew. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the current path with `request.fullpath`

If you want to get the breadcrumb then you can just split the fullpath by '/'. In the controller:

```
@path = request.fullpath
@breadcrumb = @path.split('/')
```

In the view:

```
<% @breadcrumb.each do |crumb| %>
  <%= crumb %>
  <span class="divider">/</span>
<% end %>
```

Untested, but I think it should work.